# gridview setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: java, android

I'm using a gridview to display numbers,
I want the next activity, 
when i click on any  number
but when i click on the n number nothing happens there is no error in logcat nor any force close.

Here is the code

```
public class CActivity extends Activity 
{
  GridView gridView; 

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cactivity);

             gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Abc.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            //finish();
        }
    });
}
       private void initComponent() 
       {
         gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.month_gridView);
         }
```

I don't know what the problem is but `gridView.setAdapter(adapter);` is working.  plz help

```
 gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If i use

```
  GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.month_gridView);
```

then the app force closes

logcat

```
02-07 21:10:12.721: W/dalvikvm(719): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.indianic.demo.calendark/com.indianic.demo.calendark.CalendarActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.indianic.demo.calendark.CalendarActivity.<init>(CalendarActivity.java:44)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
02-07 21:10:12.780: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  ... 11 more
02-07 21:10:18.061: I/Process(719): Sending signal. PID: 719 SIG: 9
```

I used initComponent() method before setting setOnItemClickListener()

the force close error is gone and app opens normally,

But the next activity is not opening or nothing happens.when i click on the items.
:(

AS you said i tried different cases,Still no success

```
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v3,
                int position, long id) {


            //setContentView(R.layout.abc);
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Abc.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Abc.class);
                startActivity(myIntent1);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Abc.class);
                startActivity(myIntent2);
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Abc.class);
                startActivity(myIntent3);
                break;
            case 4:
                Intent myIntent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Abc.class);
                startActivity(myIntent4);
                break;
            case 5:
                Intent myIntent5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Abc.class);
                startActivity(myIntent5);
                break;
            case 6:
                Intent myIntent6 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Abc.class);
                startActivity(myIntent6);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
          }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your custom `initComponent()` method before setting `setOnItemClickListener()`

```
public class CActivity extends Activity 
{
  GridView gridView; 

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cactivity);
    initComponent();
             gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
                  switch (position) {
                case 0://do the same for your remaining items
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Abc.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
              }
            //finish();
        }
    });
}
       private void initComponent() 
       {
         gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.month_gridView);
         }
```

Comment: thank you the Force close error is gone but nothing happens if i click on the numbers :(

Comment: there is no errors in Abc, if i use a button in cactivity using same code i.e Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Abc.class);
            startActivity(myIntent); it runs properly

Comment: same thing nothing happens

Comment: press your first item in gridview

Comment: observe in your code, the method setOnItemClickListener() has braught position of item. When you click on perticular item this method get executed. Now it's your work to catch the position and assign the task  to item

Comment: tried clicking the 1st item still nothing happens here is the print screen of the app http://www.mediafire.com/view/?n07rciajc6gyu3a

Comment: i created cases for rest of the items still nothing happens :((